# Extending and Customizing Code First Models in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

[Here is an interesting article on extending and customizing code first models in EF.](http://romiller.com/2013/02/05/extending-and-customizing-code-first-models-part-1/)
As far as the extending the object for insert is concerned, Rowan has made it very clear.

```
ModelCustomizer.RegisterModelCustomization(
    mb =>
    {
      mb.Entity<MyBizCustomer>();
    });

ModelCustomizer.RegisterTypeSubstitution<Customer, MyBizCustomer>();

var service = new CustomerService();
var customer = new MyBizCustomer { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe", IsVIP = true };
service.AddCustomer(customer);
```

Now, my problem is, if I want to use MyBizCustomer to query something with the extended model, how can I do that.
How can I query the model if I want to get all customers where IsVIP = true ?

Is there any more elegant way to allow the developers extend the existing model instead of using some key-value pair concept to implement dynamic fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the OfTYpe LINQ method to filter to entities that are MyBizCustomers and then apply your additional filter:

```
query.OfType<MyBizCustomer>().Where(c => c.IsVip)
```

Comment: I created the main query in the CustomerService.cs:                        public IQueryable<Customer> GetData()
    {
        var db = new CustomerStalkerContext();
        var customer = ModelCustomizer.Create<Customer>();
        var data = db.Customers;
        return data;
    }                                                                  Not getting any output data. Am I doing something wrong here?